# perl: capturing STDOUT- logfile ends up binary

Tags: perl, encoding, stdout

I wrote a script that feeds data into an exe program called ctffind.  The exe program outputs a bunch of data to the screen which I'm trying to capture in a logfile.

Here's what I'm using right now

```
my $logout = logfile 
open STDOUT, '>>', "$logout";
open my $PIPE1, '|-', '/opt/ctf/ctffind3_mp.exe' or die $!;
```

It works outputting everything that appeared on the screen into logfile.

If I `more $logfile` the file displays as expected it's about 5000 lines long and has about 50 lines that contain the string "final values".  In my next step I do `grep "final values" logfile` it thinks logfile is a binary file and doesn't work instead it returns:

```
Binary file logfile matches
```

How do set it so that logfile is properly encoded?
ctffind.exe is also generating binary files while it runs, is this part of the problem?

Comment: What does the `file` command tell you about your log file (i.e. do `file logfile` on the command line)?

Comment: Sounds like you have some odd zero bytes or something in there. `grep -a pattern file` is a workaround for the "Binary file matches" problem.

Comment: I've had this problem before with log files. I'll bet that you have an invisible (non-printable) character somewhere in the output. You might grep around for some of them (`^P` was one I got bitten by once before).

Comment: `grep -a` fixed it!!!  thanks!

Comment: (@tripleee:  I'd upvote if you made you comment an answer and notified me here -- if you care.)

Comment: Try using `od -c logfile | more` to see where the binary characters are.

Comment: Didn't answer your actual question (too lazy) but glad if I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found two different ways to resolve the problem, thanks to commenters' suggestions:

1. One can change the `grep logfile` to `grep -a logfile`.
2. One can use `strings logfile logfile2` to make a usable version of the logfile.

Answer (score 1):

An Ascii NUL (\000) in a file's first block is enough for Perl to call the file a "binary" one.

```
echo "hello world\000" > myfile
perl -E '$f=shift;open $fh,"<",$f or die;say -e $f && -B $f ? "binary":"text"' myfile
```

Comment: It's not Perl that's saying it's a binary file, it's grep. But it could have a similar heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `ctffind3_mp.exe` has code in it to do screen formatting such as changing colors, bolding, clearing the screen, etc.  There are a few ways you could eliminate those:

- You can pipe it through `cat -v` which will turn all nonprintables into ASCII representations (e.g. NUL becomes `^@`).
- There may be specific utilities for stripping ANSI or VT100 sequences out of text--try asking superuser.
- You could try setting `$TERM` (or in perl `$ENV{'TERM'}`) to `unknown` in the hopes that the program no longer emits any special sequences for color, bold, etc.